# Can't connect to MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, database, mysql-workbench

I just set up a MySQL database with `php-myadmin` and everything was working fine until I try to connect form `MySQLWorkbench` and from a python script. I tried creating a new user and I checked if the port was really 3306.But nothing seems to work and I don't know where to look.

Thanks!

Comment: have you read this ?
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-getting-started-tutorial-create-connection.html
which step is not working ?

Comment: I forgot to mention that the MySQL server is running on linux, and I'm on a mac. I just took a look, but when I try to test my connection I get: Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.88.153' (61)

Answer (score 0):

In your linux machine, edit my.conf

```
nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

find *bind-address = 127.0.0.1* and change **127.0.0.1** to ip of your linux server (**192.168.88.153**).

Restart the mysql server

Comment: bind-address = 127.0.0.1 was not there... so I added it and changed it to 192.168.88.153, but even after the restart it's not working

Comment: what is your linux and mysql version ?

Comment: It might also be interesting to mention that when I run "sudo service mysql restart", it started but it didn't finished (It was so long that I decided to reboot)

Comment: is 192.168.88.153 your linux server ip ? you can check again using ifconfig

Comment: are you able to access it using phpmyadmin now

Comment: Ubuntu 15.10
Yes the ip address is 192.168.88.153, I'm logged through ssh

Comment: with the new line: bind-address = 192.168.88.153, when I tried to log with "mysql -u root -p", I got:  "error: Found option without preceding group in config file: /etc/mysql/my.cnf at line: 22
Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted"

Comment: MySQL version: 5.6.28

Comment: try to change 192.168.88.153 to 0.0.0.0

Comment: then create a new account using CREATE USER 'remoteroot'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'yourpassword';GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'remoteroot'@'%';

Comment: Still get the same error with: bind-address = 0.0.0.0
So i can't log to create a new user

Comment: delete that line and restart the mysql server

Comment: I deleted the line and rebooted, I created the user but when I ran the second command I got: "ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TO 'remoteroot'@'%'' at line 1" So I changed it to :"GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'remoteroot'@'%';"

Comment: No, I tried on workbench and on Python with the new user and there is no difference

Comment: have you tried to run the python script on linux machine ?

Comment: Yes it's running on a Raspberry Pi

Comment: I mean run the python script in the same machine that mysql server is runing on

Comment: I just tried and when I change the host to "localhost" it's working, but when I use the Ip address, I get the same error

Comment: can you ping the linux machine from mac, make sure you opened the firewall port 3306

Comment: the port seems to be close

Comment: you can try to open it using ufw http://askubuntu.com/questions/174646/how-do-i-find-my-firewall-is-blocking-mysql

Comment: I used these command:  sudo ufw allow out 3306/tcp, sudo ufw allow in 3306/tcp. but the statut is inactive, does it matter ?

Comment: Sometimes taking a break can really make a difference ! I made a big mistake, the my.cnf file was not empty, it contained this: !includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/, so I checked the other files and in one of them there was an bind-address, so I changed it to 0.0.0.0, and now the remoteroot is working, but not the others

Comment: 'remoteroot'@'%' mean remoteroot can access from anywhere,  'remoteroot'@'1.2.3.4' mean remoteroot can only access from computer which ip is 1.2.3.4, you can add another account if you want

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed the steps to the documentation that Thanh Kieu pointed out?
Link: [MySQL Workbench documentaiton](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-getting-started-tutorial-create-connection.html)

Were you able to successfully complete all the steps (as in you did not skip any due to complications)?

Note: Posting this as an answer since I don't have the rep points to posts comments right now.

Comment: No, like I said, on step 2 when I click Test Connection, I get an error

Comment: I don't think that the problem come from Workbench since I can't connect from Python either, but this is just a guess

Comment: Reading the long stream of comments below. You said you enabled "it" (presuming you're talking about the port), and that it did not work. Have you tried setting it to a new port number? Check this link out if it is of any interest to you: http://askubuntu.com/questions/407847/how-to-change-mysql-port-number-in-ubuntu

Comment: by enabled it I mean the ufw, I ran: "sudo ufw status" and I got: "Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
3306/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
3306/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

3306/tcp                   ALLOW OUT   Anywhere
3306/tcp (v6)              ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)"

Comment: When I ran a port check, I got nothing: the ftp, the ssh and other port like this weren't detect